# Client should reject connection if client does not have certificate installed in TLS1.2 SQL Server encryption

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2, database-administration

I am working on TLS1.2 SQL SERVER encryption and I have done the following registry changes in server.

1. With respect to enabling TLS 1.2 protocol

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
```

2. With respect to setting Force Encryption to YES

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib]
"ForceEncryption"=dword:00000001
```

3.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\SNI11.0\GeneralFlags\Flag1\Force protocol encryption  value:0
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\SNI11.0\GeneralFlags\Flag2\Trust Server Certificate  value:0
```

After that I have created the self-signed certificate through openssl and bind to the SQL Server configuration. These all the changes are done in server. My requirement is, if the client does not have same certificate (exported certificate) or public key certificate installed in it then it should ignore the connection from server.

Please suggest a way to achieve my requirement or am I missing something?

I have not done any changes in client system.

Your help will be always appreciated.

Comment: TLS is not an authentication protocol, it is there to encrypt connection. In TLS **the client initiates a connection** to the server and verifies certificate supplied by the server. If the certificate is self signed and SQL Server is not a "trusted host", then, at least in SSMS, you will get a warning message (something along the lines of "this is not a trusted certificate"), this is the same message you would get in your web browser if you navigate to a website with self signed SSL certificate. How the client proceeds from there is up to the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you valuable response Alex , Same response we got from Microsoft as well. They suggested one more approach for the authentication i.e Extended protection in Sql server , but i don't this so its feasible in my standalone client and server .it's required domain server and authentication server . Please suggest me alex if you have any suggestion on Extended protection. Thanks again Alex :)

Comment: I have never used Extended protection in Sql server.

Comment: No problem Alex, Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has no support for (client) Certificate-Based Authentication.

See [Certificate-Based Authentication in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503611/certificate-based-authentication-in-sql-server)